# Integration with respect to some process

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes

While reading [Handbook of Survival Analysis](https://books.google.pl/books?id=t1vOBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA5&lpg=PA5&dq=Cox%20Regression%20Model%20Hans%20C.%20van%20Houwelingen%20and%20Theo%20Stijnen%20Leiden%20University%20Medical%20Center&source=bl&ots=_rpmNOve1b&sig=Fn5zroy6wm8kIU9wHU_TKduIlFM&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIvZevgsTYAhXBCpoKHVGyAPUQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) I've encounter following expression (page 10):

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\int_0^{\infty}\ln(\frac{exp(x_i^T\beta)}{\sum_jY_j(t)exp(x_j^T\beta)})dN_i(t)$, where $N_i(t)$ is defined as follows: $N_i(t)=\mathbb{1}_{\{t_i \le t, d_i = 1\}}$ and $Y_j(t) = \mathbb{1}_{\{t_i \ge t\}}$. As whole $\ln$ is independent from $N_i(t)$ I probably can take it before integral being left with $\int_0^{\infty}dN_i(t)$. But my problem is I don't quite understand what integration here means as I integrate with respect to some process. The only idea I have is that this integral is something like $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(N_i(t_k)-N_i(t_{k-1}))$, but is it? How can I interpret it?

Comment: Y(t) has to remain inside because it depends on time. Can you define x_i?

Comment: $x_i$ is just a vector of covariates

Comment: And t_i are stopping times? What are d_i?

Comment: $t_i$ are event times, $d_i$ are the information that $i$-th observation is right-censored ($d_i = 0$) or not ($d_i = 1$)

Comment: Taking a short glance at the book, $t_i$ and $d_i$ seem to be parameters (i.e. non-stochastic and given by the observations). It is an ordinary Stieltjes integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpreting the integral as a [Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral), after checking that the integrand is left-continuous and the integrator is right-continuous, we obtain

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\int_0^{\infty}\ln\Bigg(\frac{\exp(x_i^{\top}\beta)}{\sum_{j=1}^n Y_j(t)\exp(x_i^{\top}\beta)}\Bigg)dN_i(t)=\sum_{i=1}^nd_ix_i^{\top}\beta-\sum_{i=1}^nd_i\ln\Bigg(\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{\{t_i\leq t_j\}}\exp(x_i^{\top}\beta)\Bigg).$$